# DAX Measure Issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculation, measure

leads_id,   transh,        Date,               Accumulated Value
24472418,     7,        2026-03-14 00:00:00,    257420000
24472418,     6,        2025-09-14 00:00:00,    235968330
24472418,     5,        2025-03-14 00:00:00,    214516664
24472418,     4,        2024-09-14 00:00:00,    193064998
24472418,     3,        2024-03-14 00:00:00,    171613332
24472418,     2,        2023-09-14 00:00:00,    150161666
24472418,     1,        2023-04-14 00:00:00,    128710000

Here is the payment plan of specific client. 1st row (leads_id) is the id of the client, transh is the transaction number (order), date is transaction date of payment and accumulated value is payment amount. There is a dashboard in my table that has slicers as year, month(text, names of months) and other slicers. I want to create a measure that shows me for example when I choose year 2023 and month april from slicer it must show me this client's accumulated value for that period. In this case it is 128710000. When I choose year 2023 and month may (april, june, july, august) it must show 128710000 as well. Because client's next transh will be only in september of that year (2023-09-14). Until that period it must show 128710000 whenever I choose may, june, july, august of that year. When through slicer I choose september then it must show me 150161666. And so on.  I need a measure for this.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.